# applying zsh qualifiers on array elements or directly on a result of a command substitution

Tags: zsh

I did

```
a=( pacman -Qlq packagename )
```

to put files belonging to `package` into array

Why is this printing only the frist match, and how to print them all in zsh:

```
print -l ${a[(r)*i*]}
```

Also, how to apply zsh qualifiers on all array elements, say to list files
only via `(.)`

Is there an easier way to skip intermediary array in this process,
in a way to have qualifier specified on a result of a command substition?

Answer (score 3):

As [per documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Subscript-Flags) the subscript flag `(r)` will only return the first matching array element.

In order to get all matching elements you can use the `{name:#pattern}` [parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion), which removes any element maching `pattern` from the expansion. In order to remove the non-matching elements you can either use the flag `(M)` or negate the pattern with `^` (this requires the [`EXTENDED_GLOB`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Expansion-and-Globbing) option to be enabled):

```
print -l ${(M)a:#*i*}
setopt extendedglob
print -l ${a:#^*i*}
```

You can skip explicitly creating an intermediary array by just using the parameter expansion on the command substitution (`$(...)`) directly:

```
print -l ${(M)$(pacman -Qlq packagename):#*i*}
```

---

It seems that globbing qualifiers do not work with patterns inside parameter expansions. But you can enable the [`RC_EXPAND_PARAM`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Expansion-and-Globbing) option to expand every single array element within a *word* instead of the whole array. So `foo${xx}bar` with `x=(a b c)` will be expanded to `fooabar foobbar foocbar` instead of `fooa b cbar`. You can enabley it either globally with `setopt rcexpandparam` or for a specific expansion by wrapping it in `${^...}`. This way you can add a glob qualifier to each element of the filtered array. To print only elements that are paths to files, you can use

```
print -l ${^${(M)$(pacman -Qlq packagename):#*i*}}(.N)
```

This essentially takes each path and attaches `(.N)` as glob qualifier (which works, even though there are no globs). The resulting patterns are then evaluated as part of filename generation. `.` tells *zsh* to only match plain files. `N` enables the `NULL_GLOB` option for these patterns, otherwise the command would abort with an "no matches found" error, if it encounters a pattern that is not a plain file (e.g. `/usr` is a directory, so `/usr(.)` does not match any plain file on your system.).